# Python Selenium - How do you extract a link from an element with no href?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[This is the page I am working with](https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/ferrari/458-spider/beverly-hills-ca-90210?dma=&searchRadius=0&location=&isNewSearch=true&marketExtension=include&showAccelerateBanner=false&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=100)

I am trying to extract the link from the elements at the following XPATH:

`.//div[@class="display-inline-block align-self-start"]/div[1]/span[1]`

The links on those elements work correctly on the page but there is no href or any kind of link I can identify in the code. How do I extract that link with Selenium?

For context, I am trying to iterate through all listings on the page and pull the Carfax/Autocheck links from each. Some of them have an `href` attached and are easily scraped (the ones here: `.//div[@class="display-inline-block align-self-start"]/div[1]/a[1]`)
but the ones above are giving me issues.

Comment: This page has fronedend issues and browser crashes.

Comment: @MohammadMonfared - I have seen a lot of issues with this but only when moving through the site with Chromedriver...when I access through a regular browser, the site does not appear to have any issues. I suspect Autotrader has some sort of protocol in place to identify automated browsing and takes measures to prevent them from operating on the site...not sure how to circumvent these